# How to call ajax using done method promise method?

Tags: jquery

Can you please tell me how to call web service using done method . Actually I saw one developer doing it, he return all ajax and use done method where it get the response .I make same example I got the response in success method But I comment out this method so that I will get response using done method.

here is my fiddle .Please remove the security of browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/pb3QH/

```
function getWebSeviceCall(){

return $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
     type:"GET",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", url:"http:/est/a/destinationdashboard?crsCode=add",
    beforeSend:function(){
     alert("Before Comple");   
    },
   /* success:function(data){
        alert("----------------");
       console.log(data);

    },*/
    error:function(data){
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);

    },
    complete :function(data){
       alert(" Comple");     

    }


   });
}
$(document).on('click','#test',function(){


});
```

Comment: `Please remove the security of browser.`???

Answer (score 0):

Read the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Also be careful, because your function is called getWebSevice instead of getWebService.

http://jsfiddle.net/eyanez/p7XW6/

```
function getWebSeviceCall(){

return $.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://www.google.com",
    beforeSend:function(){
        alert("Before Comple");   
    },
    /* success:function(data){
        alert("----------------");
        console.log(data);
    },*/
    error:function(data){
        alert(data);
        console.log(data); 
    },
    complete :function(data){
        alert(" Comple");            
    } 
    });
}
    $(document).on('click','#test',function(){
        var request = getWebSeviceCall();
        request.done(function(response) {
        alert(response);
      });   
    });
```